# Should I keep returning to check on my question?

Tags: discussion

I just asked a question about Gmail and since I can't get into my account in the first place, an e-mail won't really help. Shall I just keep checking back here?

Answer (score 3):

Any e-mail notifications you receive are just a courtesy and shouldn't be relied on. Generally speaking, if someone asks a question here, they need to return here to get their answer(s). So, yes, keep checking back once or twice a day.

Of course, the other reason to keep checking is to respond to comments posted on your question asking for clarification and more information. Help us help you!